# Error in Tidyverse and Magrittr functions

Tags: package

I am using Rstudio and want to use the functions group_by and pipes. For this I installed magrittr and tidyverse, but inspite of having installed tidyverse &/dplyr I get the error that the function 'group_by' cannot be found.

Exact error message is 'cameradata %>%
+   group_by (Scientific.name) %>%
+   arrange(Photo.Date) %>%
+   mutate(diff = Photo.time - lag(Photo.time, default = first(value)))
Error in group_by(., Scientific.name) : 
  could not find function "group_by"'

Other error messages which I keep encountering are while trying load both tidyverse and dplyr:
1. '> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’

I have tried
1. Uninstalling and installing the packages multiple times by unchecking and checking the tick mark.
2. Loading the packages multiple times using the library command.
3. Also uninstalling and re-installing R, Rtools and Rstudio

I need the group_by and pipe functions to work, can someone please help me do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this post and your previous post about tidyverse, it seems like you have an issue with your R or RStudio installation. My advice below is for Windows, but if you are using a Mac or Linux operating system you may be facing a different issue.

One common problem is that the location of the R libraries is not writeable. For example, on a Windows machine the default install choices will place R in `C:\Program Files`, but you may not have full permissions to that folder (this is common when working on a business network where computers are managed by an IT department). Furthermore, even if you have user permissions to access that folder, the R library may still not be writeable **by R** unless you "Run as Administrator".

The easiest solution I have found is to simply install R/RStudio somewhere else. My solution is to create a folder `C:\R` and then install R/RStudio in that folder, e.g. install R as normal but set the install directory to `C:\R\R-3.6.1`. In this case you should have no permissions issues when later installing libraries with `install.packages()` or via the RStudio menus.

**Note that if you have multiple R installations, you may need to tell RStudio which R version to use**. I don't use RStudio so I can't advise on how to do this exactly, but it will probably work out if you uninstall R and RStudio, then reinstall R to `C:/R/R-3.6.1`, then reinstall RStudio to `C:\R\RStudio`.

It is certainly possible to have R installed to `C:/Program files` but specify a different location for the R library. However, the steps for setting a new location of the R library is not (in my opinion) easy for beginner R users to understand, so I tend to suggest the above solution instead. It's easy, and it has always worked for me.

Comment: Thank you So much ... I did that and now Rstudio is working :). I had to totally remove stuff from my machine and then do this.

Comment: @KeerthiKrutha Glad to hear it. If this answer solved the issue, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark so that people who search similar questions later know that this might work for them too.